# mac bundle install for jekyll error occurs

Tags: git, rubygems, jekyll

when i perform bundle install on mac this occure

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20140725-85993-z0wc6r.rb extconf.rb 
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Provided configuration options:

```
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2_2/bin/ruby
--help
--clean
--use-system-libraries
--enable-static
--disable-static
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
--enable-cross-build
--disable-cross-build
```

extconf failed, exit code 1

**Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Dong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Dong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.**

then i went to  http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html this page also with error.  what can do for this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for      help with installing dependencies.
-----
```

Just reinstall `libiconv`. It works on my machine.

Comment: I did this before, but does not work.  thanks! anyway